# Instantiating instances of subclass from the parent class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, instantiation, class-method

If I have a class B that inherits from class A, can I instantiate class B through a class method defined in class A?

```
class A
  def self.instantiate params
    # ???
  end
end

class B < A
end

b = B.instantiate 123
b.class   # => B
```

Obviously, I don't want to call `B.new` from A.  Any class that inherits from A should benefit from this.

```
class C < A; end
c = C.instantiate 123
c.class   # => C

class D < A; end
d = D.instantiate 123
d.class   # => D
```

Comment: What a lovely user name! :-)

Comment: Why not change `def self.instantiate params` to `def initialize params`? Then you can just use `new` instead of `instantiate` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `self.new` (`self` references the class itself in the class method):

```
class A
  def self.instantiate params
    self.new
    # OR simply `new`
  end
end

class B < A; end
b = B.instantiate 123
b.class
# => B

class C < A; end
c = C.instantiate 123
c.class
# => C

class D < A; end
d = D.instantiate 123
d.class
# => D
```

**UPDATE**

As Cary Swoveland commented, you can omit `self.`:

```
  def self.instantiate params
    new
  end
```

Comment: You don't need `self.` in `self.new`; `new` is sufficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: Of course, all that you have done here is simply hand-written an alias for `new`. So, you might just as well do `alias_method :instantiate, :new`. But then you might just as well call `new` … Honestly, I don't understand the requirements of the OP.